# Offering 'puja sale / discount'

Tags: halal-haram

I own an e-commerce business. Many of my competitors are offering 'puja sale.' In case you don't know, puja is a religious festival for Hindus. It's basically Eid for Hindus. Even though I'm not super religions, I do try my best to stay away from things that are Haram.

Like everyone else I want to offer discounts too. But I'm not sure if it's permissible to do so.

Please note that none of my products are specifically made for puja. I'm sure anyone who owns a business knows that discounts on festivals are great sales boosters and the products don't have to be related to the occasion itself.

Comment: why do you think offering discounts are not permissible?, provided what you sell is not specifically meant for that 'puja'. if you can be more specific add more clarity it would be easier for the community to answer, insha Allah.

Comment: I want to mention 'puja sales / discount' to specifically target the Hindu community. And this is what's lead me to post this question here. Wouldn't it promote the festival? And I don't know how else to let people know that it's for this specific occasion. I'm sure you know that relating an offer to an occasion is a strategy used by every business to maximize sales.